# The difference betwwen enforcement and execution

Tags: word-choice

Can anyone help to clariffy the difference betwwen enforcement and execution?

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about what you want / need? The way you asked, you request us to give you the dictionary entries... Please answer by editing the question.

Comment: You enforce a law, regulation or policy; you execute a plan.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, a data subject may file a petition with the court for a compulsory enforcement (instead of execution) order in order to have his/her claim satisfied?

Comment: @elee Legal definitions are specific to their context and beyond the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute an order or instruction means that someone follows the order themselves, possibly delegating it to others who may or may not be willing to follow it. There is no particular implication of obligation or constraint.

> The captain executed the general's orders.

This simply means the captain carried out the general's orders (which may or may not have involved giving orders himself).

To enforce an order means that someone ensures that an order is followed by others. The implication is that there is some obligation to follow the orders and there maybe be some resistance to the order being followed otherwise.

> The captain enforced the general's orders.

This means the captain made sure that other people followed the general's orders.